# What is the intuition behind the definition of the residual multi access inference?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection, projection-matrices

Let $\Phi$ be an $n \times N$ matrix, $\Phi_{I_{s-1}}$ be a subset of its column, $y=\Phi x_0$, $r_s=y-\Phi x_s$, $(x_s)_{I_{s-1}}=(\Phi_{I_{s-1}}^T\Phi_{I_{s-1}})^{-1}\Phi_{I_{s-1}}^{T}y$ where $(x_s)_{I_{s-1}}$ are the entries associated with $I_{s-1}$ and $(x_s)_{I^C_{s-1}}=0$. At the end of page 6 of [Sparse Solution of Underdetermined Systems](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220685918_Sparse_Solution_of_Underdetermined_Systems_of_Linear_Equations_by_Stagewise_Orthogonal_Matching_Pursuit) by Donoho he defines the $j$-th entry of the residual multi access inference as the following:

$z_s(j)=x_0(j)-\phi_j^Tr_s/||P_{I_{s-1}}\phi_j||_2^2, \quad j\notin I_{s-1}$

**Question:** From paper, what is $P_{I_{s-1}}$? Is it $P_{I_{s-1}}=(\Phi_{I_{s-1}}^T\Phi_{I_{s-1}})^{-1}\Phi_{I_{s-1}}^{T}$, correct me if I'm wrong. What is the intuition behind this definition? I mean how one would come up with this definition.